# android phonegap design issues

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

My App is  android phonegap application using html page and css.
But My Application design is varied in different emulator.
I need to get the same UI Design for all mobile devices.

**Note**

**I didnt used jquery mobile**

Here my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>PhoneGap</title>
        <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        label.custom-select 
        {
        position: relative;
        }
        .custom-select select 
        {
            display: inline-block;
            border: 2px solid #03498A;
            padding: 2px 3px 3px 50px;
            margin: 0;
            outline:none; /* remove focus ring from Webkit */
            line-height: 1.2;
            background: #03498A;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size:15pt;font:bold;
            width:80%;
            height:7%;
            -webkit-appearance:none; /* remove the strong OSX influence from Webkit */
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }

        /* for Webkit's CSS-only solution */
        @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) 
        {
            .custom-select select 
            {
                padding-right:30px;    
            }
        }

        /* Since we removed the default focus styles, we have to add our own */
        .custom-select select:focus 
        {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #c00;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #c00;
            box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #c00;
        }

        /* Select arrow styling */
        .custom-select:after 
        {
            content: "â–¼";
            position: absolute;
            top: 2%;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            font-size: 60%;
            line-height: 30px;
            padding: 0 7px;
            background-image: url(../images/dd.PNG);
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            padding-left:80%;
            color: #03498A;
            pointer-events:none;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
            border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
        }

        .no-pointer-events .custom-select:after 
        {
            content: none;
        }
        .dropdown
        {
            border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #03498A;
            border: 1px solid;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            width:260px;font-size:20pt;font:bold;
        }
        #setting
        {
            margin-left:10%;
            margin_right:5%;
        }
        #checknotify
        {
            margin-left:50%;
        }
        #checkphone
        {
            margin-left:38%;
        }
        #checklocation
        {
            margin-left:51%;
        }
        #allcauses
        {
            margin-left:2%;
        }
        #link
        {
            margin-left:20%;
        }
        #managelabel
        {
            margin-left:6%;
        }

        .checkBox
        {
            background-position: 0px 0px;
        }
        .checkBoxClear
        {
            background-position: -32px 0px;
        }
        .checkBox, .checkBoxClear
        {
            background-image: url('../images/Check.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            cursor: hand;
        }
        .checkBox1
        {
            background-position: 0px 0px;
        }
        .checkBoxClear1
        {
            background-position: -32px 0px;
        }
        .checkBox1, .checkBoxClear1
        {
            background-image: url('../images/Check.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            cursor: hand;
        }
        .checkBox2
        {
            background-position: 0px 0px;
        }
        .checkBoxClear2
        {
            background-position: -32px 0px;
        }

        .checkBox2, .checkBoxClear2
        {
            background-image: url('../images/Check.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            cursor: hand;
        }
            .checkBox3
        {
            background-position: 0px 0px;
        }
        .checkBoxClear3
        {
            background-position: -32px 0px;
        }

        .checkBox3, .checkBoxClear3
        {
            background-image: url('../images/Check.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            cursor: hand;
        }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body >
        <div>
            <div><input type="image" style="width:100%" src="../images/set.png" />
            </div>
            <div align="center" style="margin-top:2%"><input type="image" src="../images/load.png" style="width:90%" />
                <input type="image" src="../images/image.png" style="width:90%"/>
                <div style="margin-top:5%">
                    <label id="managelabel" style="width:70%;font-size:12pt">Manage Cause Settings</label>
                    <a id="link" href="javascript:help()">Help ?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="loadingScreen" align="center"></div>
            <div align="center" style="margin-top:5%"><label class="custom-select"><select name="mydropdown" style="width:90%;height:10%;font-size:15pt" >
                <option id="0" value="opt">option</option>
                </select></label>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:3%;padding:5%">
                <table>
                    <tr width="100%">
                        <td width="90%"><label>One</label></td>
                        <td><div id="Div1" class="checkBox">&nbsp;</div></td>
                        <label for="Div1"></label>
                        <td><input value='' type='checkbox' style="display:none"  /></td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr width="100%">
                        <td ><label>Two</label></td>
                        <td><div id="Div2" class="checkBox1">&nbsp;</div></td>
                        <label for="Div2"></label>
                        <td><input value='' type='checkbox' style="display:none" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr width="100%">
                        <td ><label>Three</label></td>
                        <td><div id="Div3" class="checkBox2">&nbsp;</div></td>
                        <label for="Div3"></label>
                        <td><input value='' type='checkbox' style="display:none" /></td>
                    </tr> 
                </table>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr width="100%">
                        <td><div id="Div4" class="checkBox3">&nbsp;</div></td>
                        <label for="Div4"></label>
                        <td><label style="width:60%;font-size:12pt">Here settings</label></td>
                        <td><input value='' type='checkbox' style="display:none" id='chkAllCauses'/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:32%">
            <div style="border-width:3px;padding-top:2%;padding-bottom:2%;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;background-color:#00458D;bottom:0;" align="center">
                <table width=100%>
                <input type="image" src="../images/first.PNG" style="width:23%" />
                <input type="image" src="../images/second.jpg" style="width:23%" />
                <input type="image" src="../images/third.jpg" style="width:23%" />
                <input type="image" src="../images/fourth.png" style="width:23%"/>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

I have attached the two screenshots ,I have run in different two emulator now you can simply analyze the problem.

![Image from Galaxy Tab][1]

---

Image from settingFromAndroid2.2 the bottom design is disappeared,when I scroll down then only I can view this.

![Android2.2][2]

---

**To Clear these problem am trying with footer**

Suppose i have text box in my design,

```
<input type="text"  style="width: 80%;height: 35px;font-size:15pt;border:4px solid orange" placeholder="Email Address (User ID)" />
```

I cannot able to type the text in text box,my design is collapsed while typing,here i have attached screenshot and html file .Kindly view this.
![with footer][3]

How to solve my problem?

**UpDate**
In my above code i added this line only for footer

```
    <input type="text"  style="width: 80%;height: 35px;font-size:15pt;border:4px solid orange" placeholder="Email Address (User ID)" />
      <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar"  style="height:2px;bottom:0%;padding-bottom:0%;">

    <table width=100%>
            <input type="image" src="../images/Home.PNG" style="width:23%" onClick="home()"/>
            <input type="image" src="../images/messages-menu.jpg" style="width:23%" onClick="inbox()"/>
            <input type="image" src="../images/settings-menu.jpg" style="width:23%" onClick="settings()"/>
            <input type="image" src="../images/close-menu.png" style="width:23%" onClick="callServiceFunction()"/>
            </table>
    </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but mine was showing a menu option. I think css position is destroyed upon text soft keyboard load.

```
$('#menuFooter').css('position', 'fixed');
$('#menuFooter').toggle();
```

Comment: <input id="dummy_radio" type="radio" readonly="readonly" style="opacity: 0;">

Comment: You could add a hidden input field to your html and use jquery or jq mobile to focus this hidden field upon click event of your input email field. This should hide the soft keyboard, and then set css position to fixed. <input id="dummy_radio" type="radio" readonly="readonly" style="opacity: 0;">

Answer (score 0):

Normally phonegap with jquery mobile creates these kind of issues. The footer jumping is happened in some devices. Make a footer at fixed position by the following code,

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Footer!</h1>
</div>
```

### or

You can do some css style changes to make a fixed footer by

```
[data-role=page]{height: 100% !important; position:relative !important;}
[data-role=footer]{bottom:0; position:absolute !important; top: auto !important; width:100%;}
```

### or

You can use iscroll jquery mobile plugin for fixed footer with list items. See this [Demo](http://yappo.github.com/projects/jquery.mobile.iscroll/livedemo.html)

Comment: Still my Design is collapsed,i will update my code and design